# Select element with known title attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have a select field and a couple of links with images. Clicking on these images displays another link. That works flawlessly.

Now I have, in Javascript, the text of the alt attribute of the image that has to be clicked. How can I select the right one to click the one with the same alt attribute:

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="additionalimages">
    <div class="additional-images">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <img src="image1.jpg" class="product-image" style="cursor: pointer" data-descr="">
                <a href="image1.jpg" class="product-image image-0" style="display:none;" title="ImageOne"></a>      
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <img src="image2.jpg" class="product-image" style="cursor: pointer" data-descr="">
                <a href="image1.jpg" class="product-image image-1" style="display:none;" title="ImageTwo"></a>  
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my Javascript to get the values of the select. Now I got for example the text "ImageOne". Now I want to select the a element with the title attribute ImageOne, so that I can fire a click event.

```
$(".vm-chzn-select").chosen().change(function (event) {
  console.log("Select changed");
  var colorText = $(".vm-chzn-select option:selected").text();

  $(".additionalimages").find("a.product-image").attr("title"); 



});
```

Now the last line gives me back the value, but how can I compare so I know which one to click?

Comment: It is not easy to understand what you actually mean. Provide a working code snippet will likely do that.

Comment: Ok im gonna add the extra code now, added the HTML and code so its more clear what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I assume that your `colorText` holds the selected text value `ImageOne`, you should be able to simply do like this to fire a `click` event on the anchor with the very same `title` value.

```
$(".vm-chzn-select").chosen().change(function (event) {
  console.log("Select changed");
  var colorText = $(".vm-chzn-select option:selected").text();

  $(".additionalimages a.product-image[title='" + colorText + "']").click(); 

});
```

Comment: This was the answer. The reason it didn't work is because I had to trim the text from colorText because it had an extra space. Now it works flawlessly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can select elements by attribute (and a variable) like this...

```
var altValue = "alt-tag-value";
var $img = $("img[alt='" + altValue + "']");
```

That will return the image (or images) that have the specified alt attribute value.